# The category of monoid objects in an abelian category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories

For an abelian category $\mathscr{A}$, is the category of its monoid objects $\mathrm{Mon}(\mathscr{A})$ also abelian?

In particular, is the category of dg-algebra, which is the category of monoid objects in the category of chain complexes abelian?

Comment: ...android? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: That was a typo (perhaps due to the autocomplete feature), thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The category of monoid objects in an abelian category $A$ *with respect to the cartesian product* is just $A$ again; this follows from the fact that 1) every object is canonically and uniquely a commutative monoid with respect to the coproduct and 2) in an abelian category finite products and coproducts agree.

So if you want a more interesting answer than this then you need to specify a monoidal structure on $A$. The category of chain complexes has such a monoidal structure, which is not part of its abelian category structure, and the category of monoids with respect to this monoidal structure, which is the category of dg algebras, is not enriched in abelian groups and so can't be an abelian category. Another way to see that it can't be an abelian category is that products and coproducts are very different; products are cartesian products but the coproduct is a variation on the free product.